# How can transactions be implemented in spring webflux without r2dbc driver

Tags: jdbc, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-jdbc, spring-data-r2dbc

#### General problem description

Due to compatibility issues with the provided database I can not use the provided r2dbc driver for the database. The only possible option is using the standard jdbc driver but I have faced some issues getting transactions to work in the spring-weflux/ project reactor context.

Transactions with jdbc usually rely on the requirement of the connection being thread-local. In project reactor Flux/Mono it is not guaranteed that each flux execution is performed in the same thread. Even more i assume one of the major benefits of reactive programming is the ability to switch threads without having to worry about it. For this reason the standard spring jdbc `TransactionManager` can not be used and for r2dbc a `ReactiveTransactionManager` is implemented. As I am using jdbc in this case neither can I use the `JdbcTransactionManager`, nor is a `ReactiveTransactionManager` available.

**First of all: Is there a simple solution to this Problem?**

#### "Hacky" solution

I will now elaborate further on the steps I already took to solve this issue for me. My idea was implementing a custom `ReactiveTransactionManager`, which is based on the provided `JdbcTransactionManager`. My assumption was that it would be possible to wrap a transaction around a Mono/Flux this way. The issue is that I did not take into account the issue described above: It works currently only in a ThreadLocal context as the underlying JdbcTransactions still rely on it. Due to this the inner transactions are handled (commit,rollback) individually if the thread is changed in between.

The following class is the implementation of my custom transaction manager to be included in a reactive stream.

```
public class JdbcReactiveTransactionManager implements ReactiveTransactionManager {

  // Jdbc or connection based transaction manager
  private final DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager;

  // ReactiveTransaction delegates everything to TransactionStatus.
  static class JdbcReactiveTransaction implements ReactiveTransaction {

    public JdbcReactiveTransaction(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) {
      this.transactionStatus = transactionStatus;
    }

    private final TransactionStatus transactionStatus;

    public TransactionStatus getTransactionStatus() {
      return transactionStatus;
    }

    // [...]

  }

  @Override
  public @NonNull Mono<ReactiveTransaction> getReactiveTransaction(TransactionDefinition definition)
    throws TransactionException {
    return Mono.just(transactionManager.getTransaction(definition)).map(JdbcReactiveTransaction::new);
  }

  @Override
  public @NonNull Mono<Void> commit(@NonNull ReactiveTransaction transaction) throws TransactionException {
    if (transaction instanceof JdbcReactiveTransaction t) {
      transactionManager.commit(t.getTransactionStatus());
      return Mono.empty();
    } else {
      return Mono.error(new IllegalTransactionStateException("Illegal ReactiveTransaction type used"));
    }
  }

  @Override
  public @NonNull Mono<Void> rollback(@NonNull ReactiveTransaction transaction) throws TransactionException {
    if (transaction instanceof JdbcReactiveTransaction t) {
      transactionManager.rollback(t.getTransactionStatus());
      return Mono.empty();
    } else {
      return Mono.error(new IllegalTransactionStateException("Illegal ReactiveTransaction type used"));
    }
  }
```

The implemented solution works in all scenarios where the tread does not change. But a fixed thread is not what one usually wants to archive using reactive approaches. Therefore the thread must be fixed using `publishOn` and `subscribeOn`. This is all very hacky and I myself consider this a good solution but I do not see a better alternative currently. As this is only required for one use case right now I can probably do but I would really like to find a better solution.

#### Pinning the Thread

The example below shows the situation that I need to use both: `publishOn` and `subscribeOn` to pin the thread. If I omit either on of these some statements wont be executed in the same thread. My current assumption is that Netty executes the parsing in a separate thread (or eventloop). Therefore the additional `publishOn` is required.

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> allocateFlows(ServerRequest request) {
  final val single = Schedulers.newSingle("AllocationService-allocateFlows");

  return request.bodyToMono(FlowsAllocation.class)
      .publishOn(single) // Why do I need this although I execute subscribeOn later?
      .flatMapMany(this::someProcessingLogic)
      .concatMapDelayError(this::someOtherProcessingLogic)
      .as(transactionalOperator::transactional)
      .subscribeOn(single, false)
      .then(ServerResponse.ok().build());
}
```

Comment: Since onSubscribe will pin the thread, ThradLocal can now be used. So your reasoning is contradicting itself. Since you have chosen to use JDBC you must pin the thread, since JDBC is blocking. If you dont pin the thread, you most likely will have very bad performance. You can make your solution as reactive as you wont, the database driver is internally blocking

Comment: The jdbc spec is inherently blocking, so the driver is internally blocking. The code inside the driver is blocking, so you can write your code as reactive as you want, the driver will still block and you MUST pin the thread. Its not that only transactions are blocking.

Comment: The issue is that for some reason Netty executes the parsing of the request in a separate thread which is fixed even if I use `subscribeOn` in the end. Only if I use `publisheOn` for the parameter the thread is pinned. This bothers me more than it should because it is impossible to understand the reason for the two operations intuitively.

Comment: But that problem would probably be another question

Comment: `The issue is that for some reason Netty executes the parsing of the request in a separate thread` i do not understand this statement, and since no code is either provided or even better, no minimal reproducible example, i can not comment on this.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I have added some information regarding this issue in the question. I would greatly appreciate if you'd take another look at it

Comment: I would really like to know the solution as well. Actually, I'm using coroutine of Kotlin and withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {} to isolate blocking call of JDBC to separate thread in a method in @ Service class. But, even though the method in Service class has an @ Transactional annotation, it cannot manage transaction because basically Spring uses ThreadLocal to manage transactions and I'm using separate thread to run DB query. How in earth should I do!? I think the only 2 choices are whether using R2DBC or move withContext(Dispatchers.IO) to upper layer(e.g. Controller),

Comment: but I don't think it is efficient. I think there is no advantage to use non-blocking event loop solution if i always use thread pool right after I get a request in Controller, isn't it?